# Keep removed item from a listview, ready for other tasks

Tags: android, listview

sorry if bad english

I'm kinda new in android development.
I'm working on an app and i need to fill a custom ListView. each of the ListView items got a Delete Button, which removes them from the list, the problem is that i need to keep that removed item.

**A little background:**
i am working on a "Monster Generator" app that just gives you a monster (name, desc, etc) from a "bag" (consider just a List) and places it on another list inside a java object i made, the object can keep track of the monster generated and the monsters left in the bag. i already make a functional prototype, using only TextViews but i tried to make it as ListView, and there is the problem.

in my Custom Adapter in the getView method i have

```
Button btnDelete = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_delete);
btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
     public void onClick(View v){
           items.remove(position); // this item i need to keep somehow in the activity
           notifyDataSetChanged();
           // I need to keep the item removed, ready to use in the activity 
           //and i don't know how
     }
});
```

Comment: You may have another source of data that is not affected by ListView.

Comment: One way you could do is you can just add all those removed items into another list.

Comment: i can use another list (arraylist in this case) but it will continue in my adapter class, not in the activity, i can't figure out how to pass this list to my activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, i kinda resolve it:

First of all, i think the situation of my problem may be to specific, anyway i'll post my solution.

Second, thanks to you for posting an answer.

apparently i have a really bad understanding of objects, at least in java (i am ashamed).

i just needed to change my CustomAdapterClass contructor to accept my "game logic"

```
public CustomAdapter(GameActivity activity, List<Monster> items, GameLogic gamelogic){...}
```

my "GameLogic" (this just for clarify my situation) has two ArrayList, one of MonstersInBag list(monsters that are not in game), and another of MonstersInGame list.

The MonstersInGame list, is the list i am using to fill the listview.

So i add the removed item of the listview and add it to the GameLogic - MonstersInBag, and updated a textView in my activity with a public method.

```
buttonDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            Game.getMonsterGameBag().add(items.remove(position));
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            activity.UpdateMonsterNumber();
        }
    });
```

I hope it help anyone with a specific situation like this.

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<Monster> listToKeep = new ArrayList<>();

Button btnDelete = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_delete);
    btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
         public void onClick(View v){
               listToKeep.add(items.get(position));
               items.remove(position);
               notifyDataSetChanged();

         }
    });
```

Comment: this listToKeep, will continue in the CustomAdapter class, not in the activity class itself, or is there a way i can pass this list to my activity?